# How to remove and addArrangedSubvew without view blinking?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistackview

I have some view that consists from one stackview. Every `n` second I should update this view with data from server. When the new data come, I clean stackView (with method removeFromSuperView of its children) and add arrangedSubviews again to update UI. Sometimes, server sends the same data as old data. But doing this update operation, my view is kinda shuddering. Its kinda dragging and shuddering every time I clean and add views to my stackview. Of course, I can only update my UI if oldData != newData. But this competition is difficult and hard to find correctly. So, how to update stackview with new data without shuddering and blinking?

Here is my code:

```
func configure(_ items: [Item]) {
    stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    items.forEach { 
       let someView = SomeView()
       someView.configure($0)
       stackView.addArrangedSubview(someView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why recreate a view? Why cant you create it only once and hold reference to these views and update them every n seconds that way view will be updated without any blinking

Comment: Suppose, I hold reference and store them as array like [SomeView]. But the next updated data has length greater than [SomeView] length. As you see, anyway, I should recreate view.

Comment: Why don't use you a `UICollectionView` (or a `UITableView` for that matter)? These are designed to (de)queue views

Comment: Currently not possible. Because all of the items are inside card like view. Is it possible to put tableview inside card like view and make card's height fit to tableview? I don't know currently.

Comment: @neo - what is `SomeView`? You don't have to remove and add all the arranged subviews just to update them. If you show us what `SomeView` is (and what `Item` is), I can show you a better way to do this.

Comment: @DonMag SomeView is a simple UIView that is added to stackview. I think it doesn't matter how it looks. `Item` is a simple struct. The problem is to update stackview with new data without blinking that occurs because of removeFromSuperview and addArrangedSubview afterwards. Currently, I have idea to compare `Item` by implementing Equatable protocol, but as I wrote, this comparison is not always accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing / re-adding views to the stack view...

- only add new views if there are more Items than current arranged subviews
- set the data - `configure()` - each arranged subview
- hide existing arranged subviews if there are more than needed

For example:

```
func configure(_ items: [Item]) {
    // if we have fewer arranged subviews than items
    //  add new ones
    while stackView.arrangedSubviews.count < items.count {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(SomeView())
    }
    // hide any existing arranged subviews if we have too many
    for i in 0..<stackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[i].isHidden = i >= items.count
    }
    // update the existing arranged subviews with the new data
    for (thisItem, thisView) in zip(items, stackView.arrangedSubviews) {
        // unwrap the arranged subview
        guard let v = thisView as? SomeView else {
            continue
        }
        v.configure(thisItem)
    }
}
```

Here's a complete example - the number of "items" and their data will change every 1.5 seconds:

Sample struct Item with two strings:

```
struct Item {
    var title: String = ""
    var desc: String = ""
}
```

Sample "SomeView" class with two labels:

```
class SomeView: UIView {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let descLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        titleLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        descLabel.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        [titleLabel, descLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.backgroundColor = .white // so we can see the label frames at run-time
            addSubview(v)
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            descLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),

            descLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            descLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            descLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
        ])
    }
    
    func configure(_ item: Item) -> Void {
        titleLabel.text = item.title
        descLabel.text = item.desc
    }
}
```

Sample "NeoView" class with the stack view:

```
class NeoView: UIView {

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
    }
    
    func configure(_ items: [Item]) {
        // if we have fewer arranged subviews than items
        //  add new ones
        while stackView.arrangedSubviews.count < items.count {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(SomeView())
        }
        // hide any existing arranged subviews if we have too many
        for i in 0..<stackView.arrangedSubviews.count {
            stackView.arrangedSubviews[i].isHidden = i >= items.count
        }
        // update the existing arranged subviews with the new data
        for (thisItem, thisView) in zip(items, stackView.arrangedSubviews) {
            // unwrap the arranged subview
            guard let v = thisView as? SomeView else {
                continue
            }
            v.configure(thisItem)
        }
    }
}
```

Example controller class:

```
class NeoTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let neoView: NeoView = {
        let v = NeoView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        return v
    }()
    
    var items: [[Item]] = []
    var idx: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        neoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(neoView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            neoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            neoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            neoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // no bottom constraint
        ])
        
        items = sampleData()
        
        var idx: Int = 0
        self.neoView.configure(self.items[idx % self.items.count])

        // update neoView with a new set of items every 1.5 seconds
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: true) { timer in
            idx += 1
            self.neoView.configure(self.items[idx % self.items.count])
        }
        
    }
    
    func sampleData() -> [[Item]] {

        // we'll create 8 sets of [Item] arrays
        //  each with a different number of Items
        let numItems: [Int] = [
            4, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8, 3, 5,
        ]
        
        var items: [[Item]] = []
        var i: Int = 1
        numItems.forEach { n in
            var theseItems: [Item] = []
            for j in 1...n {
                let thisItem = Item(title: "Set \(i) item \(j) title.", desc: "Set \(i) item \(j) description.")
                theseItems.append(thisItem)
            }
            theseItems[0].title = "Set \(i) has \(n) items."
            items.append(theseItems)
            i += 1
        }

        return items
    }
    
}
```